# How to evaluate a function with a quadratic argument or higher? --how to proceed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**example**
if I have a function of the form
$$f(2x+5) = 4x-3$$ and I am asked to evaluate $$f(8)$$ ,I make $$t=2x+5$$ from where
$$x= (t-5)/2$$
then $$f(t) = 4( (t-5)/2 ) -3$$ , I take $$t=8$$ and that's it.**

**Doubts**

but how do I do it here, if I do the above I get a quadratic equation or a cubic one

a)$$f( x^2 +1/x^2) =x+1/x$$ , find $$f(4)=?$$ , **x>0**
b)$$f( x^3 +1/x^3) =x+1/x$$ , find $$f(4)=?$$ , **x>0**

thank you in advance
**what is in bold is edited**

Comment: The $f$ defined in $f(x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}})=x + \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't seem to be a function (you can negate $x$ and get a different value, giving $f$ two different values for the same argument). Are there domain restrictions you forgot to put into the question?

Comment: @Joshua Wang , edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take that as:

> Find $x+\dfrac1x$ given $x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}=4$.

And this is easily solvable by algebraic methods.

**EDIT**

> Find $x+\dfrac1x$ given $x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}=4$.

Let $x+\dfrac1x=k$. Then,

We know,
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$
Putting $a=x$ and $b=\dfrac1x$, we get
$$k^3=x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}+3\times x\times\dfrac1x\times k$$
$$k^3-3k-4=0$$
Solving gives
$$k=\boxed{\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt3}+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt3}}$$

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Yes! (Edit and remove that comma to get your LaTeX compiled!)

Comment: @ultralegen5385 $x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}=x^{2}+ 2\cdot x\cdot \frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{x^{2}} -, 2 =(x+\frac{1}{x})^2-2=4 \rightarrow (x+\frac{1}{x})=\sqrt{6}$ for the first case,continued

Comment: And yes, you got your answer: $f(4)=\sqrt6$.

Comment: @untralegend5385,the second one, but I can't think of how to go on $$ x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}=x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}+3(x+\frac{1}{x})-3(x+\frac{1}{x}) =(x+\frac{1}{x})^3-3(x+\frac{1}{x})=4$$

Comment: Use the identity: $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.

Comment: Note: you have to find $x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ first.

Comment: @ultralegen5385 ,$$x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}=(x+\frac{1}{x})(x^{2}-x\cdot \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{2}})=(x+\frac{1}{x})(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1 )=(x+\frac{1}{x})(\sqrt{6}-1)=6(\sqrt{6}-1)=4$$ 
I seem to be missing something to conclude

Comment: I solved it for you. See my edit. And one more thing, don't mix the previous details with it - the two questions are totally different.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it helps to see things a different way. Instead of solving for $x$, I would have looked at the equation as

$$f(2x+5) = 4x-3 = 4x+10-10-3 = 2(2x+5)-13$$

which means $f(x) = 2x-13$. Taking the second equation we have

$$f\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = x+\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+2+\frac{1}{x^2}} = \sqrt{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+2}$$

which means $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$ if $x>0$ (you will need to clarify whether this is the case). Can you try the last one?

Comment: @NinadMunshi_good idea I will try it

Comment: @NinadMunshi_,$$f\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right) = x+\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt[3]{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3} = \sqrt[3]{x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+3(x+\frac{1}{x}})  =?????$$ , how do I give it the desired ?shape